# Default font sizes in 7.x after upgrading. Any way to change it for all dashboards?

Tags: grafana

I upgraded to 7.x from 6.5.0.

Everything is fine except minor glitches but default font size is bigger and messes up almost all my dashboards.

It seems that now the default font size is 14px instead of 13px.

Is there any way that i can make the looks the same as 6.5?

I am running Grafana in Windows environment.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/21104

But you can still edit defaults [packages/grafana-ui/src/themes/default.ts](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/19d27351e9233a814bc6a512c0a98cc0f47e61d8/contribute/style-guides/themes.md)

https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/36fa54a28887679e006b5744f0ad6e63b8d857c3/packages/grafana-ui/src/themes/default.ts#L38

and build own customized Grafana.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to download , change and test grafana on windows, but my problem is that when i run the go run build.go build command i dotn get a dist folder anywhere...So i cant take the app to deploy..Any ideas?

Comment: @e4rthdog IMHO you need to build frontend https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/contribute/developer-guide.md#frontend maybe `npm run build`. I don't know. There is no official doc for the build from the source code, so you need to checkout grafana repo and check all build script/make files, ...

Comment: `go run build.go build pkg-archive` will give you a .zip file in `dist` directory ....